# Implementing paintbrush

Tags: javascript

I wish to implement a pint brush sort of application on my site using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with help of canvas (HTML5 feature), read more [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html)

example of such an application is [CanvasPaint](http://canvaspaint.org/), you can investigate its sources to be inspired ;)